# Flask and Auth0 - How to check if user is authenticated in Jinja

Tags: flask, auth0

I'm using Auth0 for authentication in my Flask application, and wondering how to check if the user is authenticated in the Jinja template.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do something similar to how LoginManager does it:

```
{% if current_user.is_anonymous %} #<-- This here
<li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{{ url_for('user', username=current_user.username) }}">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

- using the global `g` object which is **automatically available in templates** with the `before_app_request` hook, read more on the official `Flask` [tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/):

```
@bp.before_app_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    """If a user id is stored in the session, load the user object from
    the database into ``g.user``."""
    user_id = session.get("user_id")

    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        g.user = (
            get_db().execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
        )
```

and then in your template :

```
{% if g.user %}
  <li><span>{{ g.user['username'] }}</span>
  <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Log Out</a>
{% else %}
  <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}">Register</a>
  <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Log In</a>
{% endif %}
```

- inject your `current_user` object to the [context processor](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#context-processors), `flask-login` is your good inspiration (without decorator) :

```
[..]

def _get_user():
    if has_request_context() and not hasattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user'):
        current_app.login_manager._load_user()

    return getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top, 'user', None)

[..]

def _user_context_processor():
    return dict(current_user=_get_user())
```

and then get the current app (maybe you'll need to import `current_app` object in your case)

```
[..]
    app.context_processor(_user_context_processor)
```

then you can use the `current_user` like :

```
{% if current_user.is_anonymous %} #<-- This here
<li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{{ url_for('user', username=current_user.username) }}">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
{% endif %}
```